# How could implement pixel data as Array[i][j] within iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing

How could I implement image's pixel data as

Array[i][j]= 255;

without calculating byteIndex of raw data with bytesPerPixel and bytesPerRow like that:

int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * j) + i * bytesPerPixel;

i and j are x,y coordinates of image.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What's preventing you from doing what you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do this by allocating N rows of K elements, where N is the height of the image - and K - it's width.
Like this:

```
char ** image;
image = new char*[height];
for (size_t i=0;i<height;i++)
{
image[i] = new char[width];
}
```

But! **Don't do this.** It's the words idea to operate pixels in this way. First of all, when the image data are in planar form, it operates more efficiently since there are less [cache-misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_misses). Another reason - almost all image processing libraries uses planar memory model for storing the image data in memory. 
I suggest to use ready image containers from either [**OpenCV**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (cv::Mat type) or [**Boost::Gil**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) library. I prefefer Gil much more, since in provide explicilty typed image containers, like:

- boost::gil::bgra8_image_t
- boost::gil::gray32f_image_t
- and so on...

And provide efficient and flexible way for doing color conversion (CMYK <-> HSV <-> RGBA <-> GRAY) and image transformations (90 degreee rotation, flipping, cropping, etc)